# how to show related product in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have about 10 + models where I'm showing the 3 of them. Where the name is `motors`, `drum`, `slide`. Now in these three models, one field is the same which is the name `code`.

Trying to explain:

**models.py**

```
class Motors(models.Model):
    .
    .
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    .
    .
    .

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Drum(models.Model):
    .
    .
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    .
    .
    .

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Sliders(models.Model):
    .
    .
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    .
    .
    .

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Now in the above model, they have the same field as `code`. And in the `code`, they have the same name like for eg: in one model the code is `DD1, DD2, DD3` and another model code is `DD1, DD2, DD3`.

Now in the Above, the codes are matching. So, if the user selects one motor with `Code` `DD1`. Then show the related 2 models with code `DD1` or if the user selects one drum with code `DD1`. Then show related two models items in Django

I had used add to cart functionality the code goes here.

**views.py**

```
def addProductMotor(request):
    user = request.user
    motor_id = request.GET.get('motor_id')
    motor_cart = Motor.objects.get(id=motor_id)
    Cart(user=user, motor=motor_cart).save()
    return redirect('main:index')
```

In the above, I add one product item in the cart then show related items. How it is possible?

How can I get those two related models item?

Comment: As per your given information. It doesn't seems they are related. There must have onetoone, manytoone or manytomany field

Comment: I used this on the `drum` Model. `motors = models.ManyToManyField(Motor)`. now, forward what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can show other 2 model objects using following code -

```
motor_cart = Motor.objects.get(id=motor_id)  # get motor object
code = motor_cart.code                       # get code from the model
drum = Drum.objects.get(code=code)           # get drum from the code
sliders = Sliders.objects.get(code=code)     # get sliders from the code
```

I'll recommend you to use relation between models as you want it to be related. You can use **One-to-One**, **Many-to-One**, **Many-to-Many** as per your requirement.

You'll find more at [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/)

Comment: How I will execute in HTML template?? I have motor.html then drum.html like wise. So how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join on the basis of column "code" for  selecting data from tables

Comment: How can you give some example?